# jQuery.autocomplete : how to use minLength conditionally?

Tags: jquery

on an html input for "Postal code" i have attached jQuery.autocomplete(), and mask() the following way :

```
<input type="text" name="PostCode" id="PostCode" size="10" value="<% = vPostCode %>">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#PostCode").mask("999 99");

    $("#PostCode").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./ajax.asp"
                , dataType: "jsonp"
                , data: {
                    ajax: "1",
                    action: "getPC",
                    maxRows: 10,
                    contains: request.term
                }
                , success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.PC, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.pCode + ' : ' + item.City + ' : ' + item.Region
                            , value: item.pCode
                        }
                    }));
                }
                , contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=1253"
            });
        }
        , select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#PostCode").val(ui.item.zip);
        }
        , minLength: 2
        , selectFirst: true
        , delay: 200
    });
});
</script>
```

the problem is occurred when cursor enters the empty input id="PostCode", it's filled with `"___ __"` ( 3 underscores , space and 2 underscores ), and it's normal, because of mask().
but it cause the autocomplete work because of minLength: 2

how can i tell minLength part to ignore the `"___ __"` sequence, since only numeric values are valid, or in other words - how to fire autocomplete() only when numeric values are entered by user, and ignore if nothing was entered ?

i'm using jQuery 1.71, and jquery.maskedinput 1.2.2

thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to replace $(request.term).replace("_",""),for actual text

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question here [jQuery validation plugin: accept only US, Canada and Mexic zip code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794913/jquery-validation-plugin-accept-only-us-canada-and-mexic-zip-code)

The regex expression looks like it have all what you need. (Min 2, numbers, the mask, etc.)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("zipcodeUS", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /\d{5}-\d{4}$|^\d{5}$/.test(value);
}, "The specified US ZIP Code is invalid");
```

And this one has a range that can be usefull.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ziprange", function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || /^90[2-5]\d\{2\}-\d{4}$/.test(value);
   }, "Your ZIP-code must be in the range 902xx-xxxx to 905-xx-xxxx");
```

And then you can use those rules with validate() method and the call the autocomplete.

Comment: thanx for the research, but this is not the answer of my question. all i want is to ignore mask generated `___ __` characters from causing ajax call on autocomplete !