# How to validate US ZIP code using jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for validating my form.

I want to validate the zip code as per US ZIPCode format :-

```
> 12345
> 12345-6789
> 12345 6789
```

As per my curent code its validating the zipcode should be maximum 5 and all numeric.

Please see the code below:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>

    $().ready(function () {

        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#locationSetup").validate({
            rules: {
                'Address.AddressStreet': "required",
                'Address.City': "required",
                'Address.State.Country.CountryIsoCode': "required",
                'Address.State.SubnationalIsoCode': "required",
                'Address.PostalCode': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 5,
                    digits: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                'Address.AddressStreet': "Please enter your Street Address!",
                'Address.City': "Please select your City!",
                'Address.State.Country.CountryIsoCode': "Please  select your Country!",
                'Address.State.SubnationalIsoCode': "Please  select your State!",
                'Address.PostalCode': {
                    required: "Please enter your Postal Code!",
                    minlength: "Your Postal Code must be 5 numbers!",
                    maxlength: "Your Postal Code must be 5 numbers!",
                    digits: "Your Postal Code must be 5 numbers!"
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.Step.ToString(), "Provision", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "locationSetup" } }))

<table width="100%" id="locInfo">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="30%" />
                <col />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <th><label>@AddressResource.COUNTRY_LABEL_TEXT:</label> <span class="redtext">(Required)</span></th>
                <td>
                   @* @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address.State.Country.CountryIsoCode)*@
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Address.State.Country.CountryIsoCode, ProvisioningHubProxy.GetCountriesList(),
                                htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Countries", @name = "Countries" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> <label>@AddressResource.STATES_LABEL_TEXT:</label><span class="redtext">(Required)</span></th>
                <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Address.State.SubnationalIsoCode, ProvisioningHubProxy.GetStatesList(),
                                htmlAttributes: new { @id = "States", @name = "States" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label>@AddressResource.CITY_LABEL_LABEL_TEXT:</label><span class="redtext">(Required)</span></th>
                <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.City, htmlAttributes: new { @name = "City", @id = "City" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> <label>@AddressResource.STREET_NAME_LABEL_TEXT:</label><span class="redtext">(Required)</span></th>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.AddressStreet, htmlAttributes: new { @name = "StreetName", @id = "StreetName" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label>@AddressResource.US_POSTAL_CODE_LABEL_TEXT:</label><span class="redtext">(Required)</span></th>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @name = "ZipCode", @id = "ZipCode", @required = "required" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

}

Please suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery validation plugin: accept only US, Canada and Mexic zip code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794913/jquery-validation-plugin-accept-only-us-canada-and-mexic-zip-code)

Comment: There's already a rule called `zipcodeUS` inside [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add a custom validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("zipcode", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?$/.test(value);
}, "Please provide a valid zipcode.");
```

_If you want to accept spaces<sup>1</sup> between zipcode, use `/^\d{5}(?:[\s-]\d{4})?$/` for the pattern instead.

then specify it in your options:

```
rules: {
  ...
  'Address.PostalCode': {
    ...
    zipcode: true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Note that the extension library [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) has a `zipcodeUS` validator as well (but unless you're using any of the other ones it may not make sense to include it).

---

<sup>1</sup> According to the spec, properly formatted zip codes consist of five (5) numbers or five (5) numbers follower by a hyphen (-) and four (4) additional numbers. A space shouldn't *technically* be acceptable, but I'll provide the pattern regardless.

Comment: The regex doesn't handle the space format properly: 12345 6789

Comment: @Blago: Updated answer to to accommodate.

Answer (score 16):

Simply include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) and use the `zipcodeUS` rule.

```
$("#locationSetup").validate({
    rules: {
        // rules,
        'Address.PostalCode': {
            required: true,
            zipcodeUS: true // <-- use it like this
        }
    },
....
```

If you don't want to include the `additional-methods.js` file, you can copy the following method into your code...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("zipcodeUS", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /\d{5}-\d{4}$|^\d{5}$/.test(value)
}, "The specified US ZIP Code is invalid");
```

Comment: ,if I try this it gives me error
TypeError: jQuery.validator is undefined.
Can you tell me what actually I am missing here.

Comment: @ehp, The error is telling you that the `validator` is not defined.  It simply means you did not properly include the jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: Just a note.  If you do use the additional-methods.js make sure to get the version that corresponds with the version of the validation plugin you are using.  The file here is 1.11.1 and the newest at this time as 1.12.0.  The 1.11 was giving errors with 1.12.

Comment: @TimRamsey, all that should really go without saying, since newer plugin versions will always be forthcoming.  Anyway, the latest at the time this answer was written was 1.11.1 and I must have scores of answers linked to the latest at that time.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('zipcode', function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || !!value.trim().match(/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/);
}, 'Invalid zip code');
```

Then use it like this

```
<input class="zipcode"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip code validation routines are provide in additional-methods.js but I would question why you ask for country information if you are going to invalidate the form for any country other than the US? Please remember that only about 5% of the worlds population uses a US zipcode. I would recommend you make you postcode validation routines dependent on the country actually selected by the user.