# Check if Zip Code or postal code is real

Tags: validation, zipcode, postal-code

After some searching, I haven't been able to find a definite answer.

If I am given a zip code like 11111, it is technically a valid zip code but it doesn't exist. Is there a way to check this? The same goes for a postal code like a1a a1a (valid but not real).

Comment: Check out the jQuery Validation library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011993/how-to-validate-us-zip-code-using-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: You should probably include which country you're talking about or if this is regarding any countries specifics

Comment: The USPS has an API (usable for a fee) for validating actual ZIP codes. As ZIP codes can be added as needed, they would be the only reliable source for validity.

Comment: "The same goes for a postal code like a1a a1a (valid but not real)." What country is this valid in? It looks almost like a UK postcode, but the second part always starts with a digit, so it wouldn't be valid here. "A1A 1AA" is technically a valid form, I think.

Comment: That was a Canadian one. Looks like the only solution is to compare it against a dataset. I was just foolish in thinking there would be a way to check using a few rules XD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For United States zipcodes:**

You can purchase / download databases of zip codes, which you can use in your local app.

Google for

> us zip code database

Here is one that you can use for free for non-commercial purposes (for commercial purposes you can purchase a cheap license):

http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/

There are some providers which allow you to perform remote HTTP calls, search around

Answer (score 1):

For any who stumble onto this and are using Python, this exists: https://github.com/Brobin/usps-api

It doesn't cover all the API functionality, but it makes the standard stuff much easier than constructing XML by hand.