# Contact form validations using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a contact form using this code. But I could not get appropriate validations for phone number,zip code and message.

```
$(function() {
   $("form[name='contact']").validate({    
      rules: {
        username: "required",
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        phno:"required",
        zipcode: { 
        required:true,
        zipcode:true
      },
    msg:"required"
  },
  messages: {
     username: "Please enter your username",
     email: "Please enter a valid email address",
     phno:"Please enter phone number",
     zipcode:"Please enter zip code",
     msg:"Please enter message" 
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
     form.submit();
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Are you using the validation plugin? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011993/how-to-validate-us-zip-code-using-jquery-validation-plugin

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in jquery validation plugin library use phoneUS and zipcodeUS instead of phno and zipcode.