# How to validate US zip code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the below code for validating email address using jquery.

I need to validate `zipcode` using `jquery` for US only. How can I do it using `jquery` library.

This is my jQuery code:

```
 $("#page1").on("pageinit", function() {
 $("form").validate({
   rules: {
     email: {
       required: true
     },
     password: {
       required: true
     }
   },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.insertAfter(element.parent());
   }
 });
});
```

This is my HTML and CSS:

```css
label.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  label.error {
    margin-left: 0;
    display: block;
  }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  label.error {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 22%;
  }
}
em {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: .25em;
}
</style> </head> <body> <div id="page1" data-role="page"> <div data-role="header">
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div data-role="content">
      <form method="GET">
        
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        </div>
        
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="zip">Zipcode:</label>
          <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip">
        </div>

        <input data-role="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me with this.
Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate US ZIP code using jQuery Validation plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011993/how-to-validate-us-zip-code-using-jquery-validation-plugin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZIP Code (US Postal Code) validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160550/zip-code-us-postal-code-validation)

Comment: How to use that one.. Can u explain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160550/zip-code-us-postal-code-validation  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011993/how-to-validate-us-zip-code-using-jquery-validation-plugin  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794913/jquery-validation-plugin-accept-only-us-canada-and-mexic-zip-code

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hapoxadehi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You most use regex `/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/`

```
    var isValid=/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(yourvalue);
    if(!isValid) alert("not Valid");
```